# Sorting and retrieving data from MxN matrix. Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, average

How can I make my defined functions be stored in a matrix, so if I call for the student ID, it will drop me the score and the average of the works and homework?

```
# M = Students.
# N = Homework/Week.
# Missing Homework = -1.

n=0
opcion=0
#Menu:
while True:
    print('1. Capturar calificaciones.')
    print('2. Devolver calificaciones de trabajos entregados.')
    print('3. Calcular promedio.')
    print('4. Alumnos con todos los trabajos y media mayor a 3.5')
    print('9. Salir.')
    opcion = int(input('Eliga una opci�n: '))
    if opcion == 1:
        mat = lmat(input('Introduzca el n�mero de estudiantes: '))
        calificaciones = numest (len (mat))
    if opcion == 2:
        tentr (trabjentr)
    if opcion == 3:
        durchschnitt (mat, calificaciones)
    if opcion == 9:
        exit ()
#Capture data:
def daten(d):
     mattotal = []
    calif = []
    for i in range (0, numeroest):
        numcal = input ('Introduzca el n�mero de calificaciones: ') 
        for j in range (0, numcal):
            matricula = int(raw_input('Ingrese la calificaci�n: '))
            calif.append (matricula)
        mattotal.append (calif)
    return (mattotal)
# Average.
def durchschnitt (p):
        matri=input('Introduzca matr�cula: ')
    for i in range (0, len(mat)):
        if int(mat[i])==int(matri):
            suma=0
            for j in range(0,len(calificaciones[i])):
                suma+=calificaciones[i][j]
            print suma/len(calificaciones[i])
```

How can I read from a matrix inside of this, so I can input a work and make it so if I type my student ID it will give me the work from any column?

Comment: Why is there no code in the main program ? You only defined functions but they are never called anywhere. Why would you store functions in a matrix, matrix are made to store data, not functions ?

Comment: It's not clear what this is supposed to be doing - do you have a use case example? Your average function is referencing a variable defined within another function - this won't work the way you have it written.

Comment: Do you need to use `numpy`?  Regular Python structures like dictionaries and lists (and lists of lists) should work just as well.  And databases like `sqlite3`.

Comment: Regular dictionary lists. I cannot use NumPY. I have tried a new code. I'll repost it.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you're doing, as you never call any of the functions you've generated. However, based on your description of what you want to do, it sounds like you want to use a dictionary where the dictionary keys are the Student ID